# What happens in hardware and in software when I click button in WPF application?

Tags: wpf

On my exam I had this question. I should describe everything that happens after clicking button.

Comment: If it was written the way you wrote it then the question is terrible.

Comment: Really trace it all the way to hardware?   They wanted to you to address event bubbling.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question. Did you want us to answer your exam question?

Comment: English isn't my mother language, but I think my question is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the entire kernel interrupt workflow on windows right?

Some reading that can interrest you I think:

- [Kernel-Mode Driver Architecture Design Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553208.aspx)
- [Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx)

I think the one closer to your question is :

- [User mode and kernel mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554836(v=vs.85).aspx)

I think you really should read alot about Kernel Interruption to answer to your question :)